# setInterval() doesn't update variable

Tags: javascript

I was using setInterval() and I came across some strange behavior. To illustrate this better, I made a function that simply outputs a value passed to it and increases it by one.

```
function increase(i){
    console.log(i++);
}
```

However, when I try to use this function inside of setInterval(), it fails to update the variable i.

```
let i = 0;
setInterval(increase, 1000, i);
```

When I run that, I simply get 0 printed out every second. However, if I modify the increase function to not take in any arguments, I get the correct output

```
function increase(){
    console.log(i++);
}
```

Using this version of the function, I get an output of 0, 1, 2, 3...
Does anyone have any idea of why that is? I imagine it has to do with the scope of the function, but I'm really not sure what's going on. Is there a way that I can have a function inside of setInterval that takes in an argument and changes it? Or do I simply have to change my function to not receive any arguments and set it to change a variable in the global scope?

Comment: When JavaScript is looking for `i` for your `console.log()`, it searches for it from the inner scope outwards. It sees the `i` declared in the function scope first (the argument `i`) before the one on the outer scope (`let i`). Since the one in `increase` is redefined on every iteration of `setInterval`, it will always start be zero (or `undefined` coerced to 0). Removing the `i` inside the function lets the script "see" the `i` defined in the outer scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to update a (referenced) variable outside of a function call, you will need to scope it. I wrapped the `i` variable inside of a `state` object. The `i` param is no longer the same variable as the global `i` once you create a locally scoped variable of the same name.

You cannot reassign a variable inside of a function, if it is not the original global variable.

```js
let globalState = { i: 0 };

const increase = localState => {
  console.log(localState.i++);
}

setInterval(increase, 1000, globalState);
```

Comment: @MdMahamudulHasan I think you commented on the wrong post, mate.

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought that I was only passing a reference to the increase function. Now I see that I was creating a locally scoped variable at "increase(i)". So just to clarify, when passing a primitive argument to a function, you are passing by value right? And non-primitive values are passed by a copy of a reference?

Comment: @ChristianBernal primitive types cannot be reassigned, since they are copied into the function call as local variables. On the other hand, objects passed into a function can be referenced, but not reassigned.

Answer (score 0):

It is because by passing 'i' into the function, you are not passing a reference to the global variable, rather a copy is being created.

Therefore console.log(i++) is incrementing the copy - every time it is passed in it is zero because the global variable is not updated.

Answer (score 0):

the main reason,

```
function increase(i){
    console.log(i++);
}
```

here, **i** is the local variable, so every call **i** is 0.

but when you are using like below,

```
function increase(){
    console.log(i++);
}
```

here **i** is global scope variable, so **i++** incrementing the **i** value and storing. and printing accordingly